# How can I print a string adding newlines in Java?

Tags: java, string, newline

I have a string like

```
"I am a boy".
```

I would like to print it this way

```
"I 
am 
a
boy".
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 157):

```
System.out.println("I\nam\na\nboy");

System.out.println("I am a boy".replaceAll("\\s+","\n"));

System.out.println("I am a boy".replaceAll("\\s+",System.getProperty("line.separator"))); // portable way
```

Comment: @the_prole explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925947/what-is-portability-how-is-java-more-portable-than-other-languages)

Comment: The third option is best for portability.

Answer (score 149):

You can also use [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--):

```
String x = "Hello," + System.lineSeparator() + "there";
```

Comment: In the older Java versions: `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: Shortcut: `String x = "Hello, %n there";` . Added spaces around `%n` just for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 63):

#### Example

```
System.out.printf("I %n am %n a %n boy");
```

#### Output

```
I 
 am 
 a 
 boy
```

#### Explanation

It's better to use `%n` as an OS independent new-line character instead of `\n` and it's easier than using `System.lineSeparator()`

Why to use `%n`, because on each OS, new line refers to a different set of character(s);

```
Unix and modern Mac's   :   LF     (\n)
Windows                 :   CR LF  (\r\n)
Older Macintosh Systems :   CR     (\r)
```

**LF** is the acronym of **Line Feed** and **CR** is the acronym of **Carriage Return**. The escape characters are written inside the parenthesis. So on each OS, new line stands for something specific to the system. `%n` is OS agnostic, it is portable. It stands for `\n` on Unix systems or `\r\n` on Windows systems and so on. Thus, Do not use `\n`, instead use `%n`.

Comment: see [Line Separator section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dls) in docs

Answer (score 29):

It can be done several ways. I am mentioning 2 simple ways.

1. Very simple way as below:

   ```
   System.out.println("I\nam\na\nboy");
   ```
2. It can also be done with concatenation as below:

   ```
   System.out.println("I" + '\n' + "am" + '\n' + "a" + '\n' + "boy");
   ```

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
System.out.println("I\nam\na\nboy");
```

Answer (score 13):

To make the code portable to any system, I would use:

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

This is important because different OSs use different notations for newline: Windows uses "\r\n", Classic Mac uses "\r", and Mac and Linux both use "\n".

Commentors - please correct me if I'm wrong on this...

Answer (score 8):

`\n` is used for making separate line;

**Example:**

```
System.out.print("I" +'\n'+ "am" +'\n'+ "a" +'\n'+ "boy");
```

**Result:**

```
I
am
a
boy
```

Comment: Please read other answers first. Your solution is already there.

Answer (score 7):

Platform-Independent Line Breaks:

```
finalString = "physical" + System.lineSeparator() + "distancing";
System.out.println(finalString);
```

**Output:**

```
physical
distancing
```

---

*Notes:*

- Java 6: `System.getProperty("line.separator")`
- Java 7 & above: `System.lineSeparator()`

Answer (score 6):

If you simply want to print a newline in the console you can use `\n` for newlines.

If you want to break text in Swing components you can use HTML and its `<br>`:

```
String str = "<html>first line<br>second line</html>";
```

Comment: This works for me. And I am using unicode font. This works better.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have your code os-unspecific you should use println for each word

```
System.out.println("I");
System.out.println("am");
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println("boy");
```

because Windows uses "\r\n" as newline and unixoid systems use just "\n"

println always uses the correct one

Comment: This is not a good solution to write too many System.out.println()

Comment: @op Remember that `println()` adds a newline character at the *end* of the string (not the beginning).

Comment: @Hachi, `System.lineSeparator()` or `System.getProperty("line.separator")` can used to make code system independent.

Answer (score 5):

What about `%n` using a formatter like **`String.format()`**?:

```
String s = String.format("I%nam%na%nboy");
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209771/3998458) says, its available from java 1.5 and is another way to `System.getProperty("line.separator")` or `System.lineSeparator()` and, like this two, is **OS independent**.

Answer (score 1):

Full program example, with a fun twist:

Open a new blank document and save it as `%yourJavaDirectory%/iAmABoy/iAmABoy.java`.  "iAmABoy" is the class name.

Paste the following code in and read through it.  Remember, I'm a beginner, so I appreciate all feedback!

```
//The class name should be the same as your Java-file and directory name.
class iAmABoy {

    //Create a variable number of String-type arguments, "strs"; this is a useful line of code worth memorizing.
    public static void nlSeparated(String... strs) {

        //Each argument is an str that is printed.
        for (String str : strs) {

            System.out.println(str);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //This loop uses 'args' .  'Args' can be accessed at runtime.  The method declaration (above) uses 'str', but the method instances (as seen below) can take variables of any name in the place of 'str'.
        for (String arg : args) {

            nlSeparated(arg);

        }

        //This is a signature.  ^^
        System.out.print("\nThanks, Wolfpack08!");
    } 

}
```

Now, in terminal/cmd, browse to `%yourJavaDirectory%/iAmABoy` and type:

```
javac iAmABoy.java
java iAmABoy I am a boy
```

You can replace the args `I am a boy` with anything!

Comment: You do not need two loops. Either pass `args` directly to `nlSeparated()` or make `nlSeparated()` take a scalar `String` instead of an array. First option is probably better. Also, print your signature with `println` instead of `print`.

Comment: In `main`, replace `for (String arg : args) { nlSeparated(arg); }` with just `nlSeparated(args);`. `nlSeparated` already accepts a list of `String`s. For a better explanation, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12534579/2988730

Answer (score 1):

*Go for a split.*

```
String string = "I am a boy";
for (String part : string.split(" ")) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code `String result = args[0].replace("\\n", "\n");`

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = args[0].replace("\\n", "\n");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

with terminal I can use arg `I\\nam\\na\\boy` to make `System.out.println` print out

```
I
am
a
boy
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here it is!!
NewLine is known as **CRLF**(Carriage Return and Line Feed).

- For Linux and Mac, we can use "\n".
- For Windows, we can use "\r\n".

Sample:

```
System.out.println("I\r\nam\r\na\r\nboy");
```

Result:
[image: output]

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `<br>` tag in your string for show in html pages

Comment: It's always a bad idea to embed markup in your output. You never know what display technology your users are using. Best to keep it as generic as possible, and use a formatting filter for display if needed.

Comment: I said it just works in html page, it's just a suggest for who want to show a simple text in web pages.

Answer (score -1):

Here I am using the split function. I braked String from spaces. then I used println function and printed the value.

```
    public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
              String input = "I am a boy";
              String[] opuput = input.split(" ");
          for (int i = 0; i < opuput.length; i++)
                System.out.println(opuput[i]);
         }        
}
```

Comment: `input` is not defined. That's not an issue when you're just providing some exemplary code, but this code block gives the impression of being a full runnable example (since it has a `public static void main`, however it doesn't compile. So *either* make it a short 3-line sample that references "invisible" variables or make it an actually runnable sample, this mixture is just confusing.