# insert new line in java

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833689/java-string-new-line)

I am nobbish in java.how do I insert a newline at every 10 character with the condition it must be a space ? Like

"I am boy"

out put should be

New line every string.

Comment: If the answers to your previous question don't make sense to you, it is because your question wasn't clear.  You should edit the previous question to *make it* more clear.  If you simply ask a new question, it is likely to get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: `System.out.println("I\nam\nboy");`

Answer (score 1):

```
class NewLiner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "0 2 4 6 8 10";

        char[] cs = test.toCharArray();
        int step = 10;
        int count = (int) (cs.length / step);
        int limit = count * step + 1;

        for (int i = step - 1; i < limit; i+= step) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(cs[i])) {
                cs[i] = '\n';
            }
        }

        System.out.println(new String(cs));

    }
}
```