# How to pass elements of an arrayList to variadic function

Tags: java, collections, andengine, variadic-functions

I've got an arrayList filled with elements. I would like to pass the elements of that array list as arguments to a variadic function.

My function

```
public SequenceEntityModifier(final IEntityModifier... pEntityModifiers)
```

My ArrayList

```
ArrayList<IEntityModifier> arr = new ArrayList<IEntityModifier>();
arr.add(new MoveXModifier(1, 50, 120));
arr.add(new MoveXModifier(1, 120, 50));
```

I'd like to pass it to the function as if I would pass them individually.

```
new SequenceEntityModifier( /* elements of arr here */ );
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just do:

```
new SequenceEntityModifier(arr.toArray(new IEntityModifier[arr.size()]));
```

This copies the `ArrayList` to the given array and returns it. All vararg functions can also take arrays for the argument, so for:

```
public void doSomething(Object... objs)
```

All the legal calls are:

```
doSomething(); // Empty array
doSomething(obj1); // One element
doSomething(obj1, obj2); // Two elements
doSomething(new Object[] { obj1, obj2 }); // Two elements, but passed as array
```

**One caveat:**

Vararg calls involving primitive arrays don't work as you would expect. For example:

```
public static void doSomething(Object... objs) {
    for (Object obj : objs) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3};
    doSomething(intArray);
}
```

One might expect this to print `1`, `2`, and `3`, on separate lines. Instead, it prints something like `[I@1242719c` (the default `toString` result for an `int[]`). This is because it's ultimately creating an `Object[]` with one element, which is our `int[]`, e.g.:

```
// Basically what the code above was doing
Object[] objs = new Object[] { intArray };
```

Same goes for `double[]`, `char[]`, and other primitive array types. Note that this can be fixed simply by changing the type of `intArray` to `Integer[]`. This may not be simple if you're working with an existing array since you cannot cast an `int[]` directly to an `Integer[]` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/), I'm particularly fond of the [`ArrayUtils.toObject`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(int[])) methods from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)).

Comment: Correct, ofc, but every time I write something like this I cringe - such a syntactic tangle.

Comment: @SteveB. I agree, overloading is a much better option than forcing this kind of method call, then convert behind the scenes. While varargs are nice, they don't play well with collections.

Comment: Not just a tangle; a performance hit with all the unnecessary (pointer) copying.  See my answer below for a cheaper way.

Answer (score 3):

The construct `IEntityModifier...` is syntactic sugar for `IEntityModifier[]`

See the [appropriate JLS section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.1) (*8.4.1 Formal Parameters*)

Answer (score 3):

I always create an overload that takes `Iterable< ? extends IEntityModifier >`, and make the variadic version forward to this one using `Arrays.asList()`, which is cheap.