# Unchecked warnings are not removed with Javac @SuppressWarnings annotation

Tags: java, compilation, warnings, javac, compiler-warnings

I cannot remove my warnings with unchecked cast. I believe this is very strange because I have added the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on the method but the Javac still showing the warnings.

```
[unchecked] unchecked cast (List<Integer>) getObject(LIST);
    return (List<Integer>) getObject(LIST);
    required: List<Integer>
    found:    Object
```

I have create an Example, It throws 2 warnings. I'm using Oracle JDK 1.7 update 79.

```
package strange;
import java.util.List;

public class Strange implements Constants {

    //Throw Warning
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<Integer> getList() {
        return (List<Integer>) getObject(LIST);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<Integer> getList2() {
        return (List<Integer>) getObject(LIST);
    }

    //Throw Warning
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<Integer> getOtherList() {
        return (List<Integer>) getObject(OTHER);
    }

    protected Object getObject(String key) {
        return new Object();
    }
}

interface Constants {

    public static final String LIST = "list";
    public static final String OTHER = "other";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make your title more descriptive?

Comment: @kolossus, it says 1.7u79 from Oracle in the question.

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK 1.7 update 79

Comment: @rvillablanca, It doesn't seem to reproduce with 1.8.0_45.

Comment: You are right, could be an JDK 7 bug??

Comment: @rvillablanca, give me a couple of minutes and I'll check...

Comment: [While it's not unheard of](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7141469?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel), you might [have an option (if you're using eclipse)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646770/java-6-unsupported-suppresswarningsrawtypes-warning)

Comment: I want to know why the warning still shown. Using a constant string parameter the warning is hidden, but using the static LIST var no work

Comment: @rvillablanca, the warning is most likely shown because of a bug in javac.

Comment: @aioobe, I don't have accepted the answer because I was not sure if the problem is really a true bug, but I don't have more answers and the your one match with my suspicion, it is a Javac bug ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `javac` bug. It doesn't reproduce in 1.8.0u45 though.

Did a quick search and it could be related to for instance [JDK-8016099](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016099) or [JDK-8022144](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022144). One could do a hg bisect to find the exact changeset that resolved the issue.

Possibly related:

- [Java generics SuppressWarnings("unchecked") mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829753/java-generics-suppresswarningsunchecked-mystery)