# Java 7 nio FileAttributes windows

Tags: java, windows, nio

How can i get this `File myTempDir = Files.createTempDir(Path path, String prefix, FileAttribute)` to work in windows.

I'm using java 7.  On linux I can pass a PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttributes for the 3rd parameter.

What is the equivalent fileAttributes for windows.

I think this method always expects a fileAttribute object.  Is there an empty fileAttribute that i can pass in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you took a look at the API for 
[`Files.createTempDirectory(Path, String, FileAttribute<?>...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29), you would actually see that the `FileAttribute<?>...` parameter is optional:

> attrs - an optional list of file attributes to set atomically when
>   creating the directory

And since the method is implemented using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), it is perfectly valid to omit the parameter entirely:

```
Files.createTempDirectory(Paths.get("."), "foo");
```

Comment: [Relevant answer w.r.t. varargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534531/how-to-pass-elements-of-an-arraylist-to-variadic-function/12534579#12534579). In any case, this is the "empty file attributes" that OP is looking for, so +1.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a version of Files.createDirectory() that allows you to omit the attributes.