# Portable newline transformation in Java

Tags: java, string, newline

Suppose I have a string, which consists of a few lines:

```
aaa\nbbb\nccc\n (in Linux) or aaa\r\nbbb\r\nccc (in Windows)
```

I need to add character `#` to every line in the string as follows:

```
#aaa\n#bbb\n#ccc (in Linux) or #aaa\r\n#bbb\r\n#ccc (in Windows)
```

What is the easiest and *portable* (between Linux and Windows) way to do it Java ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `line.separator` system property

```
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator") + "#"; // concatenate the character you want
String myPortableString = "#aaa" + separator + "ccc";
```

These properties are described in more detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

If you open the source code for `PrintWriter`, you'll notice the following constructor:

```
public PrintWriter(Writer out,
                   boolean autoFlush) {
    super(out);
    this.out = out;
    this.autoFlush = autoFlush;
    lineSeparator = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));
}
```

It's getting (and using) the system specific separator to write to an `OutputStream`.

You can always set it at the property level

```
System.out.println("ahaha: " + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.setProperty("line.separator", System.getProperty("line.separator") + "#"); // change it
System.out.println("ahahahah:" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

prints

```
ahaha: 

ahahahah:
#
```

All classes that request that property will now get `{line.separator}#`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly you are using, but [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)'s `printf` methods lets you write formatted strings. Withing the string you can use the `%n` format specifier which will output the platform specific line separator.

```
System.out.printf("first line%nsecond line");
```

The output:

```
first line
second line
```

(`System.out` is a `PrintStream` which also supports this).

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 7 (also noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31599937/4501084)) you can also use the method:

```
System.lineSeparator()
```

which is the same as:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

to get the system-dependent line separator string.
The description of the method from the official [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) is quoted below:

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns
>   the same value - the initial value of the system property
>   line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it
>   returns "\r\n".