# Continuing Part Of String On New Line

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

```
String noun1 = jTextField1.getText();
        String noun2 = jTextField1.getText();
        String noun3 = jTextField1.getText();

        String verb1 = jTextField1.getText();
        String verb2 = jTextField1.getText();
        String verb3 = jTextField1.getText();

        String adj1 = jTextField1.getText();
        String adj2 = jTextField1.getText();
        String adj3 = jTextField1.getText();

        String story = "This is the story about a " + noun1;

        jTextArea1.setText(story);
```

I'm creating a Madlibs with JFrame and need to find out how to continue string on a new line (I forgot) Such as story. I need it to continue so I can add the other sentences.

Comment: Do you mean a newline? The '\n' character will insert a newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **line separator**

```
String story = "This is the story about a" + System.lineSeparator() + noun1;
```

Or use `\n` for a new line

```
String story = "This is the story about a\n" + noun1;
```

Also you can use more `System.out.println(...)` commands when you want to print it out.

```
System.out.println("This is the story about a"); // Print the string inside and add a linebreak afterwards
System.out.println(noun1); // Print the value of noun1 variable
```

All of them will give you the following result:

```
This is the story about a
"your story name"
```

More information is here: [Java String new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833689/java-string-new-line)

Answer (score 3):

You mean a linebreak in the String? Then the code you are looking for is `"\n"`. E.g. the output of

```
String text = "Hello \nWorld";
```

Would be

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Don't forget to take the spaces out, otherwise it indents 'World' :)

Comment: True :-). Edited that.