# Using %n as new line

Tags: java, newline

as recommended as for example in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077906/12340711

> It's better to use %n as an OS independent new-line character instead of \n and it's easier than using System.lineSeparator()

However, the function does not work for me:

`\n`:

```
System.out.println("foo\nbar");
>>>foo
>>>bar
```

works as it should.

`%n`:

```
System.out.println("foo%nbar");
>>>foo%nbar
```

is not interpreted.

Can somebody explain me why `%n` does not work for me? Is it perhaps not longer supported or am I missing something?

Comment: `%n` only works in e.g. `System.out.printf`.

Comment: The answer you linked to is using `printf`, not `println`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java provides you the `System.lineSeparator()` constant. That will break the line in a OS independent way if you are using `println`. You can also just use `\n` in a string to break the line if you are just playing around with code. It's easy and fast. Note that `println` just prints a pure text to the console.

When you use `printf`, you will actually be using a `java.util.Formatter` to format the string **before the console output**. All details of the `java.util.Formatter` can be found at (Java 8 docs link): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

So, if you want to format a string using `println`, you will need to format it first using `java.util.Formatter` with something like:

```
String formattedStr = String.format("%s = %d %n hello", "joe", 35);
System.out.println(formattedStr);
```

Where `%s` is a string, `%d` is a integer number and `%n` a line break (described in documentation link above).

`printf` is just a shortcut to the above 2 lines of code where the `String.format` is already inside `printf` implementation.

```
System.out.printf("%s = %d %n hello", "joe", 35);
```

And you can also use `\n` in a `printf` string:

```
System.out.printf("%s = %d \n hello", "joe", 35);
```

Finally, it is important for you to understand that in a real world project you should always use `System.lineSeparator()` instead `\n` if you are not using a `java.util.Formatter` (in a `Formatter`, use `%n`). Also, you should never use `System.out.*` for real projects. Use a logging framework instead.

Answer (score 2):

`%n` is interpreted as `String` by `System.out.println()`.

To use `%n`, you must use `System.out.printf()`, like in the example you have posted.

**Note**: `\n` is interpreted as `newline` by `System.out.printf()`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the fix. What would be the approriate thing to do for:
`String foo = (var1 + "%n" + var2 + "%n"`  
->String.format()?

Comment: `String.format` is usually used to print variables. To display value normally, println or printf should be enough.